# Custom cache does not gets cleaned from admin cache management

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, full-page-cache

I am trying to clear custom created cache from Admin, but it does not work.
is their any way to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Login to your server and run the below command from your magento root directory:

```
php -r 'require "app/Mage.php"; Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();'
```

or you can do it in the following way:-

```
$rm -rf var/cache/*
$rm -rf var/session/*
```

Comment: Actually i wanted it delete it from admin, just like other cache.

Comment: i get the tag in controller, but it does not delete it.

Comment: wait then let me try it on magento 1.9 instance and i will post and ans here

Comment: Actually i had used event to clear cache & that works but i want custom cache to be cleaned just like other cache's are getting cleaned from cache management.